# Jquery, объединение чекбоксов с изменением значения

Tags: jquery

прошу помощи с Jquery. Вопрос:

- есть input type number значение которого увеличивается на 1 при нажатии одного из 2 чекбоксов и соответственно уменьшается при снятии всех чекбоксов
- оба чекбокса нажимать нельзя
- если при одном из нажатых чекбоксов нажать на второй - значение не должно увеличиваться

Суть проблемы: в приложенном коде при "перепрыгивании" с одного нажатого чекбокса на другой значение инпута увеличивается на 1, а мне нужно чтобы не увеличивалось.

```
<table class="paid_table_for_admin">

  <tr class="row_form_orders_by_date" id="row_form_orders_by_date_384">

    <td><input readonly="" class="maraphon-counter" id="maraphon_counter_id_384" name="maraphon_counter_id_384" type="number" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="credit_counter" id="credit_id_384" name="credit_id_384" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="paid_counter" id="paidid_id_384" checked="" name="paid_id_384" value="1"></td>

</tr>

</table>

$(".row_form_orders_by_date input:checkbox").click(function(){
                var idRow = this.id;
                var idRowRight = idRow.substr(10);
                var maraphon_counter_id = "#maraphon_counter_id_" + idRowRight;
                var maraphon_counter_value = $(maraphon_counter_id).val();
                var rowVar = "#row_form_orders_by_date_" + idRowRight + " input:checkbox";

                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $(rowVar).not(this).prop("checked", false);
                    $(maraphon_counter_id).val(parseInt(maraphon_counter_value) + 1);   
                    } else {
                        $(maraphon_counter_id).val(maraphon_counter_value - 1);
                    };
            });
```

Ссылка на JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SokharevS/wx35701L/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем проблема поставьте условие дополнительно.

```
if (!$(rowVar).not(this).prop("checked")) {
  $(maraphon_counter_id).val(parseInt(maraphon_counter_value) + 1);
} else {
  $(rowVar).not(this).prop("checked", false);
}
```

Ссылка на [фиддлу](https://jsfiddle.net/uzqg507L/)